# How to use environment variables in a large application

Tags: python, variables, configuration, environment-variables, configparser

I'm creating a large application on python for the control of the EV chargers and I need to have multiple environment variables in my application.

Like for example I have 3 environment variables `reservationEnabled`, `transactionEnabled` and `smartChargingEnabled`.

All of these variables are written in a .env file like this:

```
[SmartChargingCtrlr]
enabled = False
[ReservationCtrlr]
enabled = True
[TxCtrlr]
enabled = True
```

And in my program I use configparser to retrieve my variables:

```
parser = ConfigParser()
parser.read('dev.ini')
```

Now my problem is how can I use these variables to enable/disable a part of my code? I was thinking to do and `if/else` statement for each variable but I feel there's a better/more pythonic way to do this but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Those aren't environment variables - they're application-specific config options. Anyway, I suggest you create a dedicated module for the config. Then you can import the parser object and directly access its options from anywhere within the application.

Comment: @ekhumoro you are right, I'am really new with this thing of config variables. Can you please provide an example? I didn't understand all of your explanantion. Thanks

Comment: `from config import parser; txtctrlr.setEnabled(parser.getboolean('TxCtrlr', 'enabled'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a more "pythonic" or alternate way to do if/else statements. There is, though, a cleaner way.

### One line if/else statement

What you could do is make an if/else statement on one line, versus doing it across several. This can be used to call functions or define variables. You can do it like this:

```
scc = config.getboolean('SmartChargingCtrlr', 'enabled')

dothis() if scc == true else dothat()
```

This is about as simple as it gets. You could specify an array of functions, but that can tend to be a little more messy. Try searching up different ways to define if/else statements. Good luck creating your program!